# Why is NSArrayController arrangedObjects returning an NSMutableIndexSet?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSTableView which calls my delegate. I am trying to customize the behavior of one my NSTableViewCells.

Upon starting the program, I can scroll through my tableView successfully. My "UsersController.arrangedObjects" should be castable to an array, but as soon as I select an item in my tableview, "UsersController.arrangedObjects" throws an exception because it is a

<NSMutableIndexSet: 0x600000d041b0>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (91)]

and not castable as an array.

I have programmed this feature in Objective-C and have never encountered this.

Thoughts?

```
extension AppDelegate: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        print("\(String.init(describing: UsersController.arrangedObjects))");
        guard let objects:[User] = UsersController.arrangedObjects as? [User] else {
            return nil
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you bind `Selection Indexes` of the table view to `arrangedObjects` of the array controller instead of `selectionIndexes`?

Comment: You haven’t done something wierd like binding selection to arranged objects ?

Comment: Affirmative. That was the error I made. I must have inadvertently checked that box by mistake.

Comment: This is the problem when setting values in the XIB AND in code.